# tikz \foreach (miss?) behaving

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

In the code below, I expected the 3 cases (commented out) to be fully equivalent. Unfortunately (for me) the 3rd one produces a straight line from coordinate (X) to coordinate (Y).
I always thought the `\foreach` statement to just insert the code between braces into the input stream 'as is', but it doesn't seems to be the case.

What am I missing? or is this a (known) bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path 
    (0,0) coordinate(X) 
    (1,1) coordinate(A) node[minimum size=4.3pt,inner sep=0pt](nA){}
    (2,2) coordinate(B) node[minimum size=4.3pt,inner sep=0pt](nB){}
    (3,3) coordinate(Y)
    ;
  \draw[rotate=45] 
    (A) +(-7pt/2,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=7pt/2]
    (B) +(-7pt/2,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=7pt/2]
    ;
    
    % Case (1)
  %\draw (X) -- (nA) -- (nB) -- (Y) ;
  
    % Case (2)
  %\foreach \x/\y in {X/nA,nA/nB,nB/Y} {\draw (\x) -- (\y);}

    % Case (3)
  %\draw (X) \foreach \x in {nA,nB,Y} { -- (\x)};
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: The use of nodes is intentional, to deal with the arc size.
Besides, my real use case is in the scope of the tikz intersections package. In which case I do need to use a foreach to deal with the many path intersections, and then the 3rd case would be the most natural construct.

Edit 2: From the argument in the comments and the (for now) only answer. I don't need alternative ways of achieving this. I have already solved my real life case (by means of deploying a strategy based on case (2) ). My single question is: What is happening with the \foreach in the 3rd case? Why is it behaving so? That's the only question, not different, alternatives ways of avoiding it's pitfall.

Edit 3: Thanks a lot for Andrew Stacey's answer that went above and beyond my original question. I mean, my single question was, if what was happening, was expected to be? Now it is clear, it is a bug, given the way foreach is implemented and interacts with the path subsystem. Foreach does more than just expanding the code in braces replacing some variables (the foreach ones).

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` as the document class for minimal working examples, that's not its intended use (it's intended use is more of educative/documentation nature, being the bare minimum necessary to define so that LaTeX doesn't complain about a missing/invalid `\documentclass`). Instead you should use `article`.

Comment: I edited it (changing to article) and added a bit more of context to the question.

Comment: Real case (package tikzdotncross) having a named path (package intersections) and drawing a line across it 'avoiding' any intersection (by replacing the crossing points with an arc). The intersections package generates a list of coordinates of the crossing points that has to be further processed. the arcs will represent 'jumps over', so that what is left is to 'connect the dots'. I  solved my case, the brute force way, using a \foreach to first create a nodes pair list (of the form X/C1,C1/C2,C2/C3.... Cn/Y) and the process this with another \foreach as in case (2).

Comment: The brute force (case 2) do work, but what I want to know is why the third case, which I know, doesn't work, doesn't. It is not the case 'oh, avoid it because it is unpredictable'.
When drawing lines connecting nodes, as per the pgf manual, should take in account the node size/bounding box (which doesn't always is a rectangle, as in the case of an arc).

Comment: As I said, I have already solved my real case, by means of case 2. I'm not looking for alternative ways of achieving the same thing. that's not the point.
the only question I have is why the 3rd case is behaving the way it is. that's my only question.

Comment: I know of spath3, and 1st it is an overkill for what I need. 2nd, the knot and calligraphy part are well documented, but for the spath3 itself, one is left with the code alone and little help about how to use it in general.

but this all is, again, beyond the point. the question remains: why case 3 is different? just that.

I'm not looking for alternative ways, the point is just: what is happening with that \foreach.

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of `spath3`. The current version has a TikZ library overlay which makes it much more user friendly.

Comment: I see you've opened an issue on github, so here's the link https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1303

Comment: A rabbit-hole of links has led me to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649314/86 , which seems strongly related.

Comment: And https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/568071/86 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594663/86 (just noting as I think they should all be linked)

Comment: habit hole, indeed. And I see, the past questions were the same: if that was to be expected (readers misreading) or a bug/misbehavior.
That's the problem, now I realize, when looking at the tikz@foreach code, they 'optimized' it so that, it isn't just repeatedly expanding the target code, but  it is taking part of the path calculation, (and then the many groups make it a pain to keep a tab of what was done, between loops)
Trouble might also be, as you, @AndrewStacey, noticed at github, ok, your patch solve this, will it break some implementation that relies on this bug (err. feature) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Skillmon says in their comment on their answer, this is a grouping issue.  As is documented, and explored in various questions on this site, `\foreach` puts its code in a group (if memory serves me right then actually it's two groups deep) so anything that needs to be remembered from one loop to the next needs a bit of work to get it out of that grouping.  At the user level this is usually accomplished by use of the `remember` key, which Qrrbrbirlbel mentions in one of their comments on your question.

However, within a path then remembering the previous coordinate is such a useful and common thing so TikZ goes to considerable lengths (literally) to ensure that it is remembered correctly.  So TikZ installs some code at the start and end of each iteration of the loop to remember the last point(s) as if the groupings weren't there.  The code that does this is relatively long:

```
\def\tikz@foreach{%
  \def\pgffor@beginhook{%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\pgfutil@firstofone}%
  \def\pgffor@endhook{\pgfextra{%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
      \pgfutil@gobble}}%
  \def\pgffor@afterhook{%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \let\pgffor@beginhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@endhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@afterhook\relax%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \tikz@scan@next@command}%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
  \foreach}%
```

For reference, in the current version of TikZ, this starts on line 2582 of `tikz.code.tex`.

Now, when TikZ encounters a node without an anchor on a path then it inserts a break in the path by adding a `moveto` to the path.  The target of that `moveto` isn't known, though, at the point where it is encountered since it will pick the exit point on the boundary of the node that is most suitable for the next coordinate.  So it needs to record that the `moveto` has not been completed, and that when TikZ knows the next coordinate then it will complete that `moveto` prior to figuring out the rest of the next part of the path.  To flag that this needs to happen, TikZ defines a macro `\tikz@moveto@waiting` and this macro holds the node name which TikZ needs to complete the calculation.

If you look closely at the `\tikz@foreach` code that I posted above then you will see a distinct lack of reference to `\tikz@moveto@waiting` which means that this *doesn't* get updated at the end of each iteration.  That means that each time TikZ starts an iteration, `\tikz@moveto@waiting` holds its original value from outside the loop.  In your case, that's the first node `X` and that's why all your lines start from `X` and not from the previous node.

Fortunately, adding in the necessary lines isn't difficult.  Here's a patched version of `\tikz@foreach`:

```
\def\tikz@foreach{%
  \def\pgffor@beginhook{%
    \global\let\tikz@moveto@waiting\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\pgfutil@firstofone}%
  \def\pgffor@endhook{\pgfextra{%
      \global\let\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting\tikz@moveto@waiting%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
      \pgfutil@gobble}}%
  \def\pgffor@afterhook{%
    \let\tikz@moveto@waiting\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \let\pgffor@beginhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@endhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@afterhook\relax%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \tikz@scan@next@command}%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
  \global\let\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting\tikz@moveto@waiting%
  \foreach}%
```

Testable code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706591/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@patched@foreach{%
  \def\pgffor@beginhook{%
    \global\let\tikz@moveto@waiting\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\pgfutil@firstofone}%
  \def\pgffor@endhook{\pgfextra{%
      \global\let\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting\tikz@moveto@waiting%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
      \pgfutil@gobble}}%
  \def\pgffor@afterhook{%
    \let\tikz@moveto@waiting\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \let\pgffor@beginhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@endhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@afterhook\relax%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \tikz@scan@next@command}%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
  \global\let\tikz@foreach@moveto@waiting\tikz@moveto@waiting%
  \foreach}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand \FixForeach {}
{
  \let\tikz@foreach=\tikz@patched@foreach
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) \foreach \nd in {B,C} { -- (\nd) };
\end{tikzpicture}

\FixForeach

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) \foreach \nd in {B,C} { -- (\nd) };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the above code, showing three versions of a diagram which connects three nodes. In the first, the three nodes are manually connected in the right order. In the second, the original foreach code connects the second and third to the first. In the third, the patched foreach code connects them correctly again.]

---

Update: Qrrbrbirlbel noted (in a now-deleted comment) that there was still an issue with using `to`, and the github issue was linked to [Coordinate [turn] option in foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615588/coordinate-turn-option-in-foreach/615651#615651) which raises the same problem with `turn`.  Here's some code that purports to fix all of those, and possibly makes it slightly simpler to add more stuff that needs to be saved.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706591/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\def\pgffor@smugglers@cove{}
\let\tikztostart=\relax

\def\pgffor@smuggle@macro#1{%
  \pgfutil@ifx#1\relax{}{%
    \expandafter
    \pgfutil@g@addto@macro
    \expandafter
    \pgffor@smugglers@cove
    \expandafter
    {%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\def\pgffor@smuggle@dimen#1{%
  \pgfutil@ifx#1\relax{}{%
    \expandafter
    \pgfutil@g@addto@macro
    \expandafter
    \pgffor@smugglers@cove
    \expandafter
    {%
      \expandafter#1\expandafter=\the#1\relax%
    }%
  }%
}

\def\pgffor@smugglers@loot{%
  %
  \pgffor@smuggle@macro\tikz@moveto@waiting%
  \pgffor@smuggle@macro\tikztostart%
  \pgffor@smuggle@macro\tikz@tangent%
  %
  \pgffor@smuggle@dimen\tikz@lastx%
  \pgffor@smuggle@dimen\tikz@lasty%
  \pgffor@smuggle@dimen\tikz@lastxsaved%
  \pgffor@smuggle@dimen\tikz@lastysaved%
  %
}


\def\tikz@patched@foreach{%
  \def\pgffor@beginhook{%
    \pgffor@smugglers@cove
    \gdef\pgffor@smugglers@cove{}%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\pgfutil@firstofone}%
  \def\pgffor@endhook{\pgfextra{%
      \pgffor@smugglers@loot%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
      \pgfutil@gobble}}%
  \def\pgffor@afterhook{%
    \pgffor@smugglers@cove
    \gdef\pgffor@smugglers@cove{}%
    \let\pgffor@beginhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@endhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@afterhook\relax%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \tikz@scan@next@command}%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
  \pgffor@smugglers@loot%
  \foreach}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand \FixForeach {}
{
  \let\tikz@foreach=\tikz@patched@foreach
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
Paths: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Foreach Paths: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) \foreach \nd in {B,C} { -- (\nd) };
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Tos: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) to (B) to (C);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Foreach Tos: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) \foreach \nd in {B,C} { to (\nd) };
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Turns: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,.2) -- ([turn]90:1cm) -- ([turn]90:1cm) -- ([turn]90:1cm) -- ([turn]90:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Foreach Turns: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,.2) foreach \i in {1,2,3,4} { -- ([turn]90:1cm) };
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Fixed Foreach Paths: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\FixForeach
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) \foreach \nd in {B,C} { -- (\nd) };
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Fixed Foreach Tos: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\FixForeach
\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[draw] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A) \foreach \nd in {B,C} { to (\nd) };
\end{tikzpicture} \\
%
Fixed Foreach Turns: &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\FixForeach
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,.2) foreach \i in {1,2,3,4} { -- ([turn]90:1cm) };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just one correction to this fabulous answer: Since `(X)` is not a node, but a coordinate, `\tikz@moveto@waiting` will be undefined/empty on each iteration, the segments don't start at `(X)`, but at the last point the previous path ended (see the middle picture of my answer). But this also explains the behaviour in the left picture of my answer, which is indeed caused by the very same bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot (including your reply at github ;) )!
ok. so the miss behaving goes a bit deeper, but the lines coming from the 'before' point is probably a bug. Thanks again (not just for pointing out where in the code the trouble is) but for clarifying if the trouble was in the way the foreach was behaving or some need better understanding of how foreach should behave.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel fixing the to paths would require adding `\tikztostart` to the list of things to remember. Easily done, I'll update my fix.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** This is not a real answer in the sense that it solves some problem, it only illustrates the *why* of this problem more precisely than the question (without any code analysis).

In your usage `\foreach` will not change the reference point for the next line segment, so you're not drawing "only the line to (Y)", but instead are drawing three lines, `(X) -- (nA)`, `(nA) -- (nB)`, and `(nB) -- (Y)`. The issue is that the points for the collision avoidance of nodes (no idea what the correct term in Ti*k*Z/`pgf` is and too lazy to look it up) aren't recalculated, so you're drawing from the lower-left end of `(nA)` to the lower-left end of `(nB)`, crossing through your semicircle.

Still the `\foreach` inside the draw can have strange side effects. If your starting and end points aren't `coordinate`s but also `node`s, the reference point for the begin of the next line isn't moved at all and you end up with three lines with identical starting point.

Overall I'd avoid your third usage altogether, it seems rather unpredictable what the outcome will be. I have no idea whether this is a bug though!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style={minimum size=4.3pt, inner sep=0pt, draw=red}]
  \path
    (0,0) node[mynode](X){}
    (1,0) node[mynode](nA){}
    (1,1) node[mynode](nB){}
    (1,2) node[mynode](Y){}
    ;
    % Case (3)
  \draw (X) \foreach \x in {nA,nB,Y} { -- (\x)};

  \path
    (2,0) coordinate(X)
    (3,0) node[mynode](nA){}
    (3,1) node[mynode](nB){}
    (3,2) coordinate(Y)
    ;
    % Case (3)
  \draw (X) \foreach \x in {nA,nB,Y} { -- (\x)};

  \path
    (4,0) coordinate(X)
    (5,0) coordinate(nA)
    (5,1) coordinate(nB)
    (5,2) coordinate(Y)
    ;
  \draw (X) \foreach \x in {nA,nB,Y} { -- (\x)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since you have a brute force solution to this, maybe I can still provide a prettier solution (that doesn't use Ti*k*Z, but other means). The following gives correct results without you having to specify a list of coordinate pairs.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tocoordinatelist { \exp:w \__tocoordinatelist:w }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \__tocoordinatelist:w { O{--} m }
  { \exp_end: #1 ( \clist_use:nn {#2} { ) #1 ( }) }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style={minimum size=4.3pt, inner sep=0pt, draw=red}]
  \path
    (0,0) coordinate(X)
    (1,0) node[mynode](nA){}
    (1,1) node[mynode](nB){}
    (1,2) coordinate(Y)
    ;
  \draw (X) \tocoordinatelist{nA,nB,Y};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, in the case (2), I know, is drawing 3 line segments, that's the brute force way of having a foreach equivalent to case (1).
My real question is why case (3) isn't exactly the same as case (1), from my reading of pgf's manual (page 1001, section 88), it 'should be', after all, like case (1) resulting in a single path linking (X) to (nA) to (nB) and finally to (Y). That's the part that got me confused.
Edit: and the use of nodes, and not coordinates, in the foreach is intentional to account for the size of the arc command.

Comment: To add a bit of context: my real use case is in the scope of the tikz intersections package. in which case I do need to use a foreach to deal with path intersections.

Comment: @Frigeri I think you misunderstood this "answer". The reason case (3) isn't identical to case (2) is because the starting points at the intermediate nodes aren't calculated anew which this "answer" illustrates. The three different subpictures are only there to better visualise Ti*k*Z's behaviour. IMHO, the behaviour in the second subpicture (which is your case (3)) should be considered a bug, but I'm no Ti*k*Z maintainer. The other uncertainty is, whether subpicture 1 is a bug or not (and if it isn't, this is strange and for me a reason not to use `\foreach` like this).

Comment: Let me try again. YES, I DO noticed that (when using case (3)).But, as per the pgf manual, section 88, pages 1001-1003, case (3) also should be a single \draw (aka. \path[draw]) command, in which (X) is the fist coordinate, then node (nA), then node (nB) then, finally, coordinate Y. The \foreach, as per de manual doesn't actually calculate any coordinate, it is just a for, replacing the variable value and inserting whatever is the code into the stream, constructing what should be, at the end,
\draw (X) -- (nA) -- (nB) -- (Y), therefore case A. This is either a bug. OK some akward behavior.

Comment: In fact, my brute force solution was to use a foreach loop to collect, better said, to construct a clist of node pairs, and then use another foreach to implement case (2). It does works, flawless at the end. No problems at all.
that's why I said from the beginning: what is happening here? shouldn't the case (3) be equivalent (I never mentioned equal) to case (1) e the brute force, case (2).
I saw the effective behavior, and notice what is happening. the question, remains, thought, if it isn't a bug, why is it behaving so ? (the question is why, as per the manual, not perceived behavior)

Comment: @Frigeri `\foreach` doesn't calculate anything, but Ti*k*Z does if you feed it a node-coordinate thingy. And I'd guess that Ti*k*Z loses track of that point being a `node` because of the groups that `\foreach` implies, and that breaks Ti*k*Z correct calculation of the next point. But still, I did no complete code analysis. But the manual also doesn't explain my first subpicture, so I'd say documentation is either "broken" or too sparse. As I said, imho, you're right, this is a bug.

Comment: @Skillmon You're right to pinpoint grouping, see my answer for some detail.